# Liquid - if field contains content then display this html, else if empty then display nothing

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, liquid

I have a LI list which contains an image in each LI that is automatically pulled in from my CMS (my cms has fields that contain the img src). 
There are 10 images (10 li's). I need to use Liquid so that if the field DOES NOT contain any img src then display NOTHING. Otherwise if it does contain content then display the html. e.g.

```
{% if imagefield1 == imgsrc (e.g. /images/steve.jpg) %}
<li><img src="imagefield1"></li>
{% else %}
{% endif -%}

{% if imagefield2 == imgsrc %}
<li><img src="imagefield2"></li>
{% else %}
{% endif -%}
```

etc.

Can anyone help me structure my liquid if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for i in (1..10) %}
    {% capture img_src %}imagefield{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
    {% if img_src == imgsrc %}
    <li>
      <img src="{{ img_src}}">
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Please define value of imgsrc